# Constexpr is this correct behaviour?

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

I'm not sure this is correct behaviour. So I hadn't messed with constexpr before and want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding something about the spec. Testing in the way MSDN mentions to test it. If I put a breakpoint in the function and it gets skipped then it was evaluated at compile time. Is the behaviour below normal?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn956974.aspx

1. It only seems to work with optimization on period.
2. It only works if I set the value to a constexpr variable or in specific use cases that have NOTHING to do with the input variable.

So for some reason this works

```
constexpr unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n)
{
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : n*factorial(n - 1);
}
constexpr unsigned int value = factorial(5);
std::cout << value << std::endl;
```

but this gets ran at run time

```
constexpr unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n)
{
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : n*factorial(n - 1);
}

std::cout << factorial(5) << std::endl;
```

Seems kinda inconvenient to have to make a constexpr variable. It seems to work in some other specialized cases.

```
switch (fnv1a("Hello"))
{
case fnv1a("GoodBye"):
    std::cout << "GoodBye" << std::endl;
    break;
case fnv1a("Hello"):
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    break;
default:
    break;

}
```

This case initialized the case values to constants but the call in the switch statement doesn't evaluate to a constexpr and gets ran at run time.

Also equality operators seem to work for some reason so. This example only calls fnv1a once for the dynamic value.

```
void isValue(const char* str)
{
    if (fnv1a(str) == fnv1a("Hello"));
    std::cout << "Found it!" << std::endl;
}
```

I know MSVC has had some issues with compliance, but the behaviour not evaluating to a constant based on the use case rather then if the input is constant just seems odd to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you observe is correct. A `constexpr` function is required to be called at compile-time on constant expressions only. This includes the cases where the return value of a `constexpr` function is used as an initializer for `constexpr` variables, or as the value for a non-type template parameter.

In all other cases, the compiler is not required to evaluate the function at compile-time.